# Computer sounds playing through Skype

Tags: windows-8.1, skype

Whenever I have a Skype call with someone else they always end up hearing my PC sounds through Skype (Game music, sound effects etc...).

I've looked through all of the options I can find to try and disable this so that they only hear my Microphone, but so far nothing has fixed this (its easy enough to test with the Skype Echo / Sound Test Service)

I use a headset so there is no chance that the sound is being picked up through speakers from the microphone (in fact they can still hear my Music even if the microphone is muted).

How can I get it so that people I call on Skype only hear my microphone, and not my PC sounds?

Comment: "(Game music, sound effects, porn movies, etc....)"
Sorry, just had to.

Comment: what if you go to ctrl panel..sounds do you have multiple recording devices listed there maybe you can mute more than one  and see what happens? see this pic from win7 you might be able to adapt for win8  and try it http://i.imgur.com/HXmyqIY.png

Answer (score -1):

Your microphone settings are set to "What you hear". Whether that be in the Windows settings (Adjustable by right clicking the volume system tray icon and going to "Recording Devices") or in Skypes settings (I don't have Skype installed at the moment but if you poke around in the settings they will have an option that is similar).

Change these to your microphone rather than "What you hear" and you'll be in business.

Comment: that is a really confusing answer 'cos it sounds like you're talking about a windows setting, but there's no such standard windows setting like that. It looks like you are talking about what is described here https://mediarealm.com.au/articles/stereo-mix-setup-windows-10/   Stereo Mix as recording device, i.e. the computer is set to record what comes out the speakers rather than what goes into the mic from outside.

Comment: Talking about changing a microphone setting between recording from mic and not recording from mic, is nonsense. What you mean is is the recording devices window, chaning the recording device from microphone to stereo mix.

Comment: Also, saying a computer records "what you hear" is completely confusing and misleading.  A computer doesn't really know what you hear.  And actually what goes into the mic from the room is a far closer approximation to what one hears, than what comes out of the speakers. So even your usage of a confusing term seems wrong.

Comment: The setting is called "What you hear"... Take it up with Microsoft if you don't like how they named the settings, my description of the steps to fix the OPs problem are correct.

Comment: It'd help if you linked to a picture and is this only windows 8, and not windows 7 and 10?  I can't see it at that mediarealm.com link(which is win10), and I haven't seen it in win7, and I can't see it in google images, so it's a bit obscure. That information would make your answer much clearer